# jsdocs backbone generated docs missing tags

Tags: backbone.js, jsdoc

Running the jsdoc command to generate the html files, I don't get any errors. The module:collections/queue module and QueueCollection class show up as expected.

None of the @see tags show in the docs, they are ignored. I can't figure out why.

Also how can I get the docs to display the line number of the described members and methods?
For Example: `Source: collections/queue.js, line 51`

```
define([
"backbone",

// models
"models/entry"
],

/** 

@exports collections/queue
@requires Backbone
@requires modules:models/entry
@example
// Load collection
require(['collections/queue'], function(QueueCollection) {
    var queue = new QueueCollection();
});         
*/
function(Backbone, EntryModel) {
/** 
    @constructor
    @see {@link http://www.backbonejs.org/#Collection}
    @augments Backbone.Collection
*/
var QueueCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend(/**  @lends module:collections/queue~QueueCollection.prototype */{
    /**
       The model for this collection
       @see {@link http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model|Backbone docs}
       @type module:models/entry
     */
    model: EntryModel,

    /** 
        The API for requests
       @see {@link http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url}
    */

    url: '/queues',

    /**
     * @description Constructor called on class initialization 
     */
    initialize: function(){
    },
});

// Required, return the module for AMD compliance
return QueueCollection;

});
```

Comment: If I run jsdoc 3.2.2 on the data you show in your question, I cannot reproduce the problem you report. The `@see` tags produce links and the source file name and line numbers are visible.

Comment: I'm running 3.3.0-dev, could it be a bug?

Comment: My first run was with 3.3.0-dev but I was not able to reproduce with that either. However, I've just done a `git pull` to bring it in line with the very latest and then I *can* reproduce what you get. So yes, it is a bug. The solution would be to use the latest released version: 3.2.2. 3.3.0-dev is alpha.